# Having Problems Building Qt Quick App using C++ and Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I am trying to build a C++ app using Qt Quick. However, while CMake generates build file successfully, I am having errors while building the app. This app actually nothing as of now, which means, it is just a way to build.

**Here is my Top level CMake file**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(CGPA_Calculator VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Dev_Install/Qt/6.6.1/mingw_64" CACHE PATH "Qt6 install path")
set(Qt6_DIR "D:/Dev_Install/Qt/6.6.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6" CACHE PATH "Qt6 cmake directory")

find_package(Qt6 6.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(QML_Files)
qt_add_qml_module(app
    URI Calc
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        QML_Files/Main.qml
        QML_Files/Page1.qml
        QML_Files/Body.qml
        QML_Files/ContHead.qml
    #    SOURCES
    #src/cgpa_calculator.cpp src/cgpa_calculator.h
)


set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)


target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS app
    BUNDLE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    )
```

---

**Here, I would Like to add that:**

*OS Environment: Windows 11*

*Qt version: 6.6.1*

*Compiler: g++ from mingw64 (MSYS2)*

*Command Line tool: Powershell*

---

**My Directory looks like this:**

```
PS O:\CGPA Calculator> tree .
Folder PATH listing for volume Coding
Volume serial number is 6CE9-894C
O:\CGPA CALCULATOR
├───build
│   ├───.qt
│   │   └───bin
│   ├───.rcc
│   ├───Calc
│   │   └───QML_Files
│   ├───CMakeFiles
│   │   ├───3.28.1
│   │   │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       └───tmp
│   │   ├───all_qmllint.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmllint_json.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmllint_module.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmltyperegistrations.dir
│   │   ├───app_app_raw_qml_0.dir
│   │   ├───app_automoc_json_extraction.dir
│   │   ├───app_other_files.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmake_Calc.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmlcachegen.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint_json.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint_module.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmltyperegistration.dir
│   │   ├───app_tooling.dir
│   │   ├───CMakeScratch
│   │   ├───pkgRedirects
│   │   └───Progress
│   ├───QML_Files
│   │   └───CMakeFiles
│   └───src
│       ├───.rcc
│       │   └───qmlcache
│       ├───CMakeFiles
│       │   ├───app.dir
│       │   │   ├───.rcc
│       │   │   │   └───qmlcache
│       │   │   ├───app_autogen
│       │   │   └───__
│       │   │       └───.rcc
│       │   │           └───qmlcache
│       │   │               └───app_QML_Files
│       │   ├───app_autogen.dir
│       │   └───app_autogen_timestamp_deps.dir
│       ├───meta_types
│       └───qmltypes
├───CMakeExtras
│   ├───.qt
│   │   └───bin
│   ├───.rcc
│   ├───Calc
│   │   └───QML_Files
│   ├───CMakeFiles
│   │   ├───3.28.1
│   │   │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       └───tmp
│   │   ├───all_qmllint.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmllint_json.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmllint_module.dir
│   │   ├───all_qmltyperegistrations.dir
│   │   ├───app_app_raw_qml_0.dir
│   │   ├───app_automoc_json_extraction.dir
│   │   ├───app_other_files.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmake_Calc.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmlcachegen.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint_json.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmllint_module.dir
│   │   ├───app_qmltyperegistration.dir
│   │   ├───app_tooling.dir
│   │   ├───CMakeScratch
│   │   └───pkgRedirects
│   ├───QML_Files
│   │   └───CMakeFiles
│   └───src
│       ├───.rcc
│       │   └───qmlcache
│       ├───CMakeFiles
│       │   ├───app.dir
│       │   │   ├───.rcc
│       │   │   │   └───qmlcache
│       │   │   ├───app_autogen
│       │   │   └───__
│       │   │       └───.rcc
│       │   │           └───qmlcache
│       │   │               └───app_QML_Files
│       │   ├───app_autogen.dir
│       │   └───app_autogen_timestamp_deps.dir
│       ├───meta_types
│       └───qmltypes
├───QML_Files
└───src
```

**And I am trying to generate build files with these:**

```
PS O:\CGPA Calculator> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -S . -B ".\build"
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
-- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE
-- Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Dev_Install/Qt/6.6.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:2768 (message):
  Qt policy QTP0001 is not set: ':/qt/qml/' is the default resource prefix
  for QML modules.  Check https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-cmake-policy-qtp0001.html
  for policy details.  Use the qt_policy command to set the policy and
  suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Dev_Install/Qt/6.6.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:468 (__qt_internal_setup_policy)
  D:/Dev_Install/Qt/6.6.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:716 (qt6_add_qml_module)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (qt_add_qml_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done (2.7s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: O:/CGPA Calculator/build
```

**And after this when I try to build I get this error:**

```
PS O:\CGPA Calculator> cmake --build .\build
[  4%] Automatic QML type registration for target app
Error 5 while parsing O:/CGPA Calculator/build/src/meta_types/qt6app_metatypes.json: illegal value
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\app_tooling.dir\build.make:135: src/app_qmltyperegistrations.cpp] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:444: CMakeFiles/app_tooling.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
```

---

**Note That**

- Running `qml .\QML_Files\Main.qml` runs the file without any issue
- I am only using C++ to build the app, and not using anything interconnected other than that

---

I can't figure out what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: What is the illegal value in qt6app_metatypes.json?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, it shouldn't make anything crazy as it is created by the cmake.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm curious what it wrote there.

Comment: The qt6app_metatypes.json is empty

Comment: List your files using the `tree` command, not `ls`.

Comment: @smr I have added the tree command

Comment: Use `tree /F` to include files as well. Additionally, there is no need for the `build` and `CMakeExtras` directories, so you can delete them.

I don't see any problems with your current CMake file. However, you have two `add_subdirectory` commands in your CMake file, but you haven't included their sources in your question. There is a possibility that the problem is caused by them.

Besides this, you haven't added any executable targets. Don't you want an executable output?